# How do I get the global user object?

Tags: users, 8, theming

How do I get the global user object in `hook_preprocess_page()`?

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
public function behave() {
  $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  if ($account->id() == 1) {
    return "Hi, boss!";
  }
  else {
    return "You are not the site administrator.";
  }
}
?>
```

Note that in neither case is the value an actual User object. Rather, as of Drupal 8 it is a UserSession object, which duplicates some, but not all, of the information of a user. It may also represent the Anonymous User rather than a saved User entity. See [link](https://drupal.org/node/2017231) for more information.

Comment: only two lines are sufficient $account = \Drupal::currentUser();  $account->id()

Comment: @KamalOberoi sure but the code is a much better example than just having those two lines IMO.

Comment: $account->id() is returning string not integer so if you want to compare with an integer value you should us if ((int) $account->id() == 1)